# What output should be sanitized?

Tags: php, pdo, sanitization

Security is a big concern for me. The last version of my site had little to no security and we experienced a lot of issues so this time around i am looking to have things as secure as possible.

All user input goes through a function that strips tags( allowing `<p><b>` and trims the string. It is then uploaded to the site using a pdo prepared statement.

I am now going back to output everything and I am wondering what exactly needs to be sanitized. I have a lot of queries that fetch integers ( epoch time,and id's etc. ) should they be sanitized to avoid any issues?

I also have specific sections that use `<P>` and `<b>` tags from user input like about me on the user profile etc. Is my `Output_paragraph` function incorrect?

```
// Output Sanitation
function output($input) {
    $output = htmlspecialchars($input);

    return $output;
}

// Paragraph Output Sanitation
function output_paragraph($input) {
    $output = htmlspecialchars($input);
    $output = htmlspecialchars_decode($output);

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what the output is.  We need to know more.

Comment: Output would vary from news article titles, news article content, usernames, user url's, and the list goes on.

Comment: Your output_paragraph() does nothing.  It encodes them then decodes them right back to what they were.

Comment: How would i go about outputting the <p> and <b> tags only, when i just user output function the p and b tags do not format properly they just display <p> <b>

Comment: Yes, that would be the point of the htmlspecialchars() function.  You don't usually want user input to be interpreted as HTML code because of cross site scripting (XSS).  strip_tags() allows for excluded tags, maybe that will meet your functionality.

Comment: The input is sanitized and strip tags is used and it allows p and b tags with that alone i should be fine when it comes to xss correct?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, output should be sanitized when it can't be trusted. In 99% of all cases, this means user input. So raw echoing user input, for instance, is an invitation for someone to use your site to to load, say, an attack file and trick some user into clicking a link to your site that loads said data.

`htmlspecialchars` is a good start, but you need to make sure you're not trusting user entered data. That means you define what you expect, and then match it to what you can output. Maybe you need `strip_tags` too. Maybe you need a regex. There's no real "one size fits all" answer to security.